# What's difference between MySql IN and ANY operator?

Tags: mysql

**Data**

[image]

**Dump**

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `birth_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `state` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `points` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
INSERT INTO `customers` VALUES (1,'Babara','MacCaffrey','1986-03-28','781-932-9754','0 Sage Terrace','Waltham','MA',2273);
INSERT INTO `customers` VALUES (2,'Ines','Brushfield','1986-04-13','804-427-9456','14187 Commercial Trail','Hampton','VA',947);
INSERT INTO `customers` VALUES (3,'Freddi','Boagey','1985-02-07','719-724-7869','251 Springs Junction','Colorado Springs','CO',2967);
INSERT INTO `customers` VALUES (4,'Ambur','Roseburgh','1974-04-14','407-231-8017','30 Arapahoe Terrace','Orlando','FL',457);
INSERT INTO `customers` VALUES (5,'Clemmie','Betchley','1973-11-07',NULL,'5 Spohn Circle','Arlington','TX',3675);
INSERT INTO `customers` VALUES (6,'Elka','Twiddell','1991-09-04','312-480-8498','7 Manley Drive','Chicago','IL',3073);
INSERT INTO `customers` VALUES (7,'Ilene','Dowson','1964-08-30','615-641-4759','50 Lillian Crossing','Nashville','TN',1672);
INSERT INTO `customers` VALUES (8,'Thacher','Naseby','1993-07-17','941-527-3977','538 Mosinee Center','Sarasota','FL',205);
INSERT INTO `customers` VALUES (9,'Romola','Rumgay','1992-05-23','559-181-3744','3520 Ohio Trail','Visalia','CA',1486);
INSERT INTO `customers` VALUES (10,'Levy','Mynett','1969-10-13','404-246-3370','68 Lawn Avenue','Atlanta','GA',796);
```

Following works fine

```
SELECT * FROM sql_store.customers
where customer_id in(
    1,2
);
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM sql_store.customers
where customer_id = any(
    select 1
);
```

but following not

```
SELECT * FROM sql_store.customers
where customer_id = any(
    1,2
);
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM sql_store.customers
where customer_id in(
    select 1,2
);
```

Is ANY made to be used with subqueries which returns table and IN which returns list?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What's difference between MySql `IN` and `ANY` operator?

There is 2 differences between them.

1. `IN` is an operator whereis `ANY` is not, it is a keyword and may be treated as a comparison operator modifier (the same for `ALL` and `SOME`).

See [Operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/non-typed-operators.html) and [Operator Precedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html). `IN` is listed in both whereas `ANY`, `ALL` and `SOME` are not.

2. `IN` may process an expression list whereas `ANY` cannot.

For example, the code

```
WHERE t1.id IN ((SELECT id FROM t2), (SELECT id FROM t3))
```

cannot be converted into `= ANY` form without subqueries code rewrite.

---

In all other respects they are complete synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=73757a295ebfbab26b2c2e128fe982d4)

The ANY keyword, which must follow a comparison operator, means “return TRUE if the comparison is TRUE for ANY of the values in the column that the subquery returns.” [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html)

The docs also say that `SOME` is an alias for `ANY`